# Passing a GET value from HTML form to Twitter API 1.1 PHP

Tags: php, forms, get, twitter

I'm only new and learning so thanks for any advice you can give :) I'm making a really simple tool to retrieve specific data from a Twitter API 1.1 GET request for a school project. I'm using J7mbo's [TwitterAPIExchange.php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) and format. I created an HTML form to pass data to the array and can POST requests to the API without a problem. I can also successfully print specific data from a GET request to the API when I enter the variables into the $getfield in the PHP, but when I try and use a form to send  data for GET requests I get the following errors:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/exp/TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 158

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/exp/screen1.php on line 31

Here is the code:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
    if(!empty($_GET ['screen_name'])) {
    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'consumer_key' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'consumer_secret' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    );

    /** URL for REST request, see: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/ **/
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json';
    $getfield = $_GET['screen_name'];
    $requestMethod = 'GET';

    /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                ->performRequest();

    ##This prints out the fields I am interested in##

    $arrResults = json_decode($response,true);

    foreach ($arrResults['users'] as $arrSearchResult) {
$strTweet = $arrSearchResult['created_at'] ;
$strTweet1 = $arrSearchResult['screen_name'] ;
    print_r("<div class='tweet'>$strTweet $strTweet1</div>");
}       
    }

    ?>
    <h3>Enter the name here</h3>
    <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="screen_name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

So, I'm thinking that the request is being malformed before OAuth, because I get the same errors even when I don't have access keys in the OAuth array.

In POST requests to the API, form data is passed directly into the API call array, but the GET requests are built differently, and I'm not seeing how to pass form data to it. This will work fine:

```
    $getfield = '?screen_name=TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME';
```

It's when I try $getfield = $_GET['screen_name']; That it goes wrong. Thanks for your time, sorry if this noob stuff is annoying :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$getfield = '?screen_name=TWITTER_SCREEN_NAME';` works without form data, then you should just need to change the line

```
$getfield = $_GET['screen_name'];
```

to

```
$getfield = "?screen_name=".$_GET['screen_name'];
```

Assuming you're only passing through the `@handle` through in the form

Also, *(this is not pertinent to your issue)* the line `if(!empty($_GET ['screen_na...` shouldn't have a space inbetween the `$_GET` and the `[`.

Comment: Ahh I was thinking the $_GET was passing that already, which it wasn't. Thanks, that fixes the Undefined Offest error. I am still getting this though:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/exp/screen1.php on line 31

Comment: If you `print_r($arrResults);` before the foreach loop, does it print the array, or is it blank?

Comment: YEY It works!! :))) I went back to an earlier save and added  $getfield = "?screen_name=".$_GET['screen_name'];
Now it prints correctly and no errors at all! I also removed the space between the $_GET as you mentioned, that was a mistake hehe.

I cannot thank you enough, I'm loving learning PHP sometimes I think i try and go too fast lol, but thank you so much :)