# Twitter API 1.1 - everything is fine but sometime it returns null

Tags: php, twitter

```
<?php
include ("TwitterAPIExchange.php");
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "2239564530-xxxxxxxxx",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "Fu8ASZzoxxxxxxxxxxxx",
'consumer_key' => "Idrxxxxxxxxx",
'consumer_secret' => "sKwriKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
);
$getfield = '?screen_name=xxxxxxxxx&count=20';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest();
$recentTwittes = array();
$recentTwittes = json_decode($response,true);
?>
<div class="box-twitter">
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
<?php foreach($recentTwittes as $singleTwitte){?>
<li>
<div class="twitter-marker" style="padding-bottom:30px">
<p>
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/#!/<?=$singleTwitte['user']['screen_name']?>">
<?php echo '<img src="'.$singleTwitte['user']['profile_image_url'].'" /> - '.$singleTwitte['user']['name'].' - '.$singleTwitte['text']; ?>  
</a>
</p>
</div>
</li>
<?php }?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Code run fine but sometime NULL in twitter response that cause to generate error for foreach loop as invalid argument supplied for foreach() . I am unable to figure out what is going wrong. I have regenerate Oauth keys as well as consumer key. If this return my twittes at once then why it is returning null at sometime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860524/passing-a-get-value-from-html-form-to-twitter-api-1-1-php I have read this but sometimes it is returning null

Answer (score 0):

Usually, issues with NULL are because of a **certificate issue** on your end. These issues starting popping up (mainly for Windows / Mac users) after I "disabled SSL peer verification"  from the cURL options to prevent "Man in the middle" attacks. This is causing issues for people with invalid cert configs. You can see the issue and resolution for this [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/14).

Really, I need to sort out throwing an exception when cURL has an error.

**Proper Fix**

Sort out your certificate issues. [Method Here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/issues/21#issuecomment-23699461).

> I'm on Windows (using XAMPP) and found that following [these instructions](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/) fixed the problem for me. Download the [CA root certs from here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), stick it in your PHP folder and then add the following line to your php.ini file: curl.cainfo=c:\php\cacert.pem. Change the path to the .pem file in the above snippet.

**Quick Fix**

Could you try re-adding `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` in the `performRequest()` method in `TwitterAPIExchange.php` and see how that goes for you. Do this at your own peril.

Comment: Can I add curl.cainfo=domain/folder1/folder2/cacert.pem. I don't have access to hosting

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that part of the problem is about encoding the string to be searched. I helped me a little and started getting less NULLs. I used **rawurlencode($query)** before inserting my query to the **$url**.

Another related issue seems to be related to time, not sure if it's realted to twitter closing the connection to your server to then open another one, if it's realted to your application processing or any other potential variable. So I added a simple delay **usleep(100000);** before calling the next search from twitter and it worked.

Comment: Of course you can try to decrease the delay to find your sweet spot.