# Passing a GET value from HTML form to Twitter API 1.1 PHP using The Search API

Tags: php, html, twitter

Having read the [The Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) as part of Twitter’s v1.1 REST API and searching here I am still stumped as to how to format the query.

[K.Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2593355/k-jack) was able to [get it working with a search for screen names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860524/passing-a-get-value-from-html-form-to-twitter-api-1-1-php) and I thought I could use his code and adapt it but no such luck.

Here is code for what I have working using a static search term in the getfield area and including the form I am trying to incorporate.

I am searching for tweets. In K.Jack's issue he was using the search for screename and had his question answered with this snippet;

```html
$getfield = "?screen_name=".$_GET['screen_name'];
```

```html
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
 
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
    $settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'consumer_key' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    'consumer_secret' => "MY_KEY_HERE",
    );
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=question&count=1';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
 foreach($string as $items)
  {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    echo "". $items[$i]['text']. "<br />";
   }
  }
  print  ($_GET['question']);
?>
<h3>Enter the name here</h3>
    <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="question" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

This is my first question here. I tend to muddle through learning by experimenting but I have spent too long on this with too little php knowledge and just had to ask.

thank you

Comment: $getfield = '?q=question&count=1';   --- would seem to indicate you're asking Twitter for tweets about "question".  Are you certain you don't want a variable in this string?

Comment: I do want a variable, sorry I didn't make that clear. I posted that as working code.  I need to replace "question" with the variable. thanks

Comment: I got it working for a while with this   $getfield = "?q=".$_GET['question'];  but then i started getting a message from twitter that i was missing query parameters. I checked my connection which was good but no luck with the new snippet.  It worked for about ten different tries then stopped.

Comment: Is there anything strange about the strings you are using?  Sometimes character issues come into play.  Sorry, about the only idea I have on it this late in the day.  #tired_brain  #too_much_code_today

Comment: Thanks Kkinsey. it's all strange to me.  I never got it working again after that one evening so there must be some sort of interpretation urlencoding thing happening somewhere.  i just realized it's also calling TwitterAPIExchange.php so there is lots to look over.  I may hire someone one fiverr to do it.  I am wondering how I can pass him the code though without the access tokens and consumer secret thing and expect him to get it running.

Comment: You need to hire someone who has their own Twitter API key, I guess.  There should be some people out there like that.  Not me ... I waste enough time on other social media though. ;)  Best of luck.